# Unpacking and using external modules with PySpark inside Kubernetes

Tags: python, apache-spark, kubernetes, pyspark

I have been struggling with this.

Kubernetes (not that matters minikube itself is working fine. In one of the module called configure.py  I am importing yaml module

import yaml

This is throwing errors

```
import yaml
```

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'yaml'

I have been through a number of loops.

First I created  virtual environment pyspark_venv.tar.gz that includes yaml module and past it to spark-submit as follows

```
+ spark-submit --verbose --master k8s://192.168.49.2:8443 '--archives=hdfs://50.140.197.220:9000/minikube/codes/pyspark_venv.tar.gz#pyspark_venv' --deploy-mode cluster --name pytest --conf 'spark.kubernetes.namespace=spark' --conf 'spark.executor.instances=1' --conf 'spark.kubernetes.driver.limit.cores=1' --conf 'spark.executor.cores=1' --conf 'spark.executor.memory=500m' --conf 'spark.kubernetes.container.image=pytest-repo/spark-py:3.1.1' --conf 'spark.kubernetes.authenticate.driver.serviceAccountName=spark-serviceaccount' --py-files hdfs://50.140.197.220:9000/minikube/codes/DSBQ.zip hdfs://50.140.197.220:9000/minikube/codes/testyml.py



Parsed arguments:
  master                  k8s://192.168.49.2:8443
  deployMode              cluster
  executorMemory          500m
  executorCores           1
  totalExecutorCores      null
  propertiesFile          /opt/spark/conf/spark-defaults.conf
  driverMemory            null
  driverCores             null
  driverExtraClassPath    $SPARK_HOME/jars/*.jar
  driverExtraLibraryPath  null
  driverExtraJavaOptions  null
  supervise               false
  queue                   null
  numExecutors            1
  files                   null
  pyFiles                 hdfs://50.140.197.220:9000/minikube/codes/DSBQ.zip
  archives                hdfs://50.140.197.220:9000/minikube/codes/pyspark_venv.tar.gz#pyspark_venv
  mainClass               null
  primaryResource         hdfs://50.140.197.220:9000/minikube/codes/testyml.py
  name                    pytest
  childArgs               []
  jars                    null
  packages                null
  packagesExclusions      null
  repositories            null
  verbose                 true



Unpacking an archive hdfs://50.140.197.220:9000/minikube/codes/pyspark_venv.tar.gz#pyspark_venv from /tmp/spark-d339a76e-090c-4670-89aa-da723d6e9fbc/pyspark_venv.tar.gz to /opt/spark/work-dir/./pyspark_venv



printing sys.path
/tmp/spark-20050bca-7eb2-4b06-9bc3-42dce97118fc
/tmp/spark-20050bca-7eb2-4b06-9bc3-42dce97118fc/DSBQ.zip
/opt/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip
/opt/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9-src.zip
/opt/spark/jars/spark-core_2.12-3.1.1.jar
/usr/lib/python37.zip
/usr/lib/python3.7
/usr/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages

 Printing user_paths
['/tmp/spark-20050bca-7eb2-4b06-9bc3-42dce97118fc/DSBQ.zip', '/opt/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip', '/opt/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9-src.zip', '/opt/spark/jars/spark-core_2.12-3.1.1.jar']
checking yaml
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/spark-20050bca-7eb2-4b06-9bc3-42dce97118fc/testyml.py", line 18, in <module>
    main()
  File "/tmp/spark-20050bca-7eb2-4b06-9bc3-42dce97118fc/testyml.py", line 15, in main
    import yaml
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'yaml'
```

This is the source file testyml.py

```
import sys
import os
import pkgutil

def main():
    print("\n printing sys.path")
    for p in sys.path:
       print(p)
    user_paths = os.environ['PYTHONPATH'].split(os.pathsep)
    print("\n Printing user_paths")
    print(user_paths)
    #help("modules")
    print("checking yaml")
    import yaml

if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```

Well it does not matter if it is yaml or numpy. It just cannot find the modules. How can I find out if the gz file is unpacked OK?

Thanks

Thanks @rajan.

This is the requested outputs:

```
2021-07-21 07:16:37,129 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Unpacking an archive hdfs://50.140.197.220:9000/minikube/codes/pyspark_venv.tar.gz#pyspark_venv from /tmp/spark-2d88780c-6425-42f7-bc47-aa988f62a1df/pyspark_venv.tar.gz to /opt/spark/work-dir/./pyspark_venv

 printing sys.path
/tmp/spark-2d88780c-6425-42f7-bc47-aa988f62a1df
/tmp/spark-2d88780c-6425-42f7-bc47-aa988f62a1df/DSBQ.zip
/opt/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip
/opt/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9-src.zip
/opt/spark/jars/spark-core_2.12-3.1.1.jar
/usr/lib/python37.zip
/usr/lib/python3.7
/usr/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages

 Printing user_paths
/tmp/spark-2d88780c-6425-42f7-bc47-aa988f62a1df/DSBQ.zip
/opt/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip
/opt/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9-src.zip
/opt/spark/jars/spark-core_2.12-3.1.1.jar

 python version
3.7.3 (default, Jan 22 2021, 20:04:44)
[GCC 8.3.0]

looping over pkg_resources.working_set
setuptools 57.2.0
pip 21.1.3
wheel 0.32.3
six 1.12.0
SecretStorage 2.3.1
pyxdg 0.25
PyGObject 3.30.4
pycrypto 2.6.1
keyrings.alt 3.1.1
keyring 17.1.1
entrypoints 0.3
cryptography 2.6.1
asn1crypto 0.24.0
```

Now from inside the docker image

```
 docker run -it 79806723a695 bash
+ exec /usr/bin/tini -s -- bash

185@26ae74b96d20:/opt/spark/work-dir$ python3
Python 3.7.3 (default, Jan 22 2021, 20:04:44)
[GCC 8.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

>>> import sys
>>> import os
>>> import pkgutil
>>> import pkg_resources
>>> for p in sys.path:
...   print(p)
...

/usr/lib/python37.zip
/usr/lib/python3.7
/usr/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages
>>> user_paths = os.environ['PYTHONPATH'].split(os.pathsep)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/os.py", line 678, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key) from None
KeyError: 'PYTHONPATH'
>>> v = sys.version
>>> print(v)
3.7.3 (default, Jan 22 2021, 20:04:44)
[GCC 8.3.0]
>>> for r in pkg_resources.working_set:
...   print(r)
...
setuptools 57.2.0
pip 21.1.3
wheel 0.32.3
six 1.12.0
SecretStorage 2.3.1
pyxdg 0.25
PyGObject 3.30.4
pycrypto 2.6.1
keyrings.alt 3.1.1
keyring 17.1.1
entrypoints 0.3
cryptography 2.6.1
asn1crypto 0.24.0
```

I need to check if virtual environment is installed inside the docker and how to activate it?

Now user root trying to install pyyaml

```
185@26ae74b96d20:/opt/spark/work-dir$ id
uid=185(185) gid=0(root) groups=0(root)
185@26ae74b96d20:/opt/spark/work-dir$ pip3 install pyyaml
WARNING: The directory '/.cache/pip' or its parent directory is not owned or is not writable by the current user. The cache has been disabled. Check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you should use sudo's -H flag.
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting pyyaml
  Downloading PyYAML-5.4.1-cp37-cp37m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (636 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 636 kB 1.1 MB/s
Installing collected packages: pyyaml
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/.local'
Check the permissions.
```

Cheers

Also inside the docker these are the packages available

```
185@26ae74b96d20:/opt/spark/work-dir$ pip3 list
WARNING: The directory '/.cache/pip' or its parent directory is not owned or is not writable by the current user. The cache has been disabled. Check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you should use sudo's -H flag.
Package       Version
------------- -------
asn1crypto    0.24.0
cryptography  2.6.1
entrypoints   0.3
keyring       17.1.1
keyrings.alt  3.1.1
pip           21.1.3
pycrypto      2.6.1
PyGObject     3.30.4
pyxdg         0.25
SecretStorage 2.3.1
setuptools    57.2.0
six           1.12.0
wheel         0.32.3
```

This dockerfile is provided by Spark and listed below

The file itself Dockerfile has this content from

```
https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-kubernetes.html
# Building Docker image from provided Dockerfile
#docker build -t spark:latest -f kubernetes/dockerfiles/spark/Dockerfile .
/opt/spark/bin/docker-image-tool.sh -r pytest-repo -t 3.1.1 -p ./kubernetes/dockerfiles/spark/bindings/python/Dockerfile build
```

It is run as non root user called hduser

```
ARG base_img

FROM $base_img
WORKDIR /

# Reset to root to run installation tasks
USER 0

RUN mkdir ${SPARK_HOME}/python
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt install -y python3 python3-pip && \
    pip3 install --upgrade pip setuptools && \
    # Removed the .cache to save space
    rm -r /root/.cache && rm -rf /var/cache/apt/*

COPY python/pyspark ${SPARK_HOME}/python/pyspark
COPY python/lib ${SPARK_HOME}/python/lib

WORKDIR /opt/spark/work-dir
ENTRYPOINT [ "/opt/entrypoint.sh" ]

# Specify the User that the actual main process will run as
ARG spark_uid=185
USER ${spark_uid}
```

Comment: Couple of troubleshooting tips, 1. Can you confirm the Python3.7 is used -print(sys.version) 2. Make sure the required packages are installed in the right location and accessible by python (pkg_resources.working_set) ? 3. Do you need to activate virtual env in your image? 4. When you exec into the container, are you able to activate python and import yaml?

Comment: Added additional content as requested by @Rajan

Answer (score 0):

I believe I have sorted out this now.

The clue lies in the fact that this line

```
archives=hdfs://$HDFS_HOST:$HDFS_PORT/minikube/codes/${pyspark_venv}.tar.gz#${pyspark_venv} \
```

for one reason or other does not work. When printing the OS relevant stuff

```
 printing sys.path
/tmp/spark-8669fa0e-7864-4d2d-8fb4-5d0f2d068f5a
/tmp/spark-8669fa0e-7864-4d2d-8fb4-5d0f2d068f5a/DSBQ.zip
/opt/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip
/opt/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9-src.zip
/opt/spark/jars/spark-core_2.12-3.1.1.jar
/usr/lib/python37.zip
/usr/lib/python3.7
/usr/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages

 Printing user_paths
/tmp/spark-8669fa0e-7864-4d2d-8fb4-5d0f2d068f5a/DSBQ.zip
/opt/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip
/opt/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9-src.zip
/opt/spark/jars/spark-core_2.12-3.1.1.jar
```

That gz file is not on the path so python cannot pick it up and untar and unzip it.
However, if you zip your package dependencies in your virtual environment as follows

Under venv you have

```
lib/python3.7/site-packages
```

Assuming you have your requirements.txt you run below

```
# https://blog.danielcorin.com/posts/2015-11-09-pyspark/
zip -r ../dependencies.zip .
# Don't forget -> . at the end of the line
```

so you create that zip from parent directory i.e. lib/python3.7

```
lib/python3.7
(airflow_virtualenv) [root@rhes76 python3.7]# ls dependencies.zip
dependencies.zip
```

Then I simply put that file in HDFS directory that kubernetes can see
You then run your spark-submit as follows:

```
        spark-submit --verbose \
           --master k8s://$K8S_SERVER \
           --deploy-mode cluster \
           --name pytest \
           --conf spark.kubernetes.namespace=spark \
           --conf spark.executor.instances=1 \
           --conf spark.kubernetes.driver.limit.cores=1 \
           --conf spark.executor.cores=1 \
           --conf spark.executor.memory=500m \
           --conf spark.kubernetes.container.image=${IMAGE} \
           --conf spark.kubernetes.authenticate.driver.serviceAccountName=spark-serviceaccount \
           --py-files hdfs://$HDFS_HOST:$HDFS_PORT/minikube/codes/DSBQ.zip,hdfs://$HDFS_HOST:$HDFS_PORT/minikube/codes/dependencies.zip \
           hdfs://$HDFS_HOST:$HDFS_PORT/minikube/codes/${APPLICATION}
```

Note that I have now two zips separated by ',' no space under --py-files

Then your kunernetes should see it as they are in the path now

```
 printing sys.path
/tmp/spark-8669fa0e-7864-4d2d-8fb4-5d0f2d068f5a
/tmp/spark-8669fa0e-7864-4d2d-8fb4-5d0f2d068f5a/DSBQ.zip
/tmp/spark-8669fa0e-7864-4d2d-8fb4-5d0f2d068f5a/dependencies.zip
/opt/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip
/opt/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9-src.zip
/opt/spark/jars/spark-core_2.12-3.1.1.jar
/usr/lib/python37.zip
/usr/lib/python3.7
/usr/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages

 Printing user_paths
/tmp/spark-8669fa0e-7864-4d2d-8fb4-5d0f2d068f5a/DSBQ.zip
/tmp/spark-8669fa0e-7864-4d2d-8fb4-5d0f2d068f5a/dependencies.zip
/opt/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip
/opt/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9-src.zip
/opt/spark/jars/spark-core_2.12-3.1.1.jar
```

I have modified my main.py file to show this

```
from __future__ import print_function
import sys
import os
import pkgutil
import pkg_resources

def main():
    print("\n printing sys.path")
    for p in sys.path:
       print(p)
    user_paths = os.environ['PYTHONPATH'].split(os.pathsep)
    print("\n Printing user_paths")
    for p in user_paths:
       print(p)
    v = sys.version
    print("\n python version")
    print(v)
    print("\nlooping over pkg_resources.working_set")
    for r in pkg_resources.working_set:
       print(r)
    import yaml
    import numpy as np
if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```

And I know it finds the packages as it is OK with yaml but has some issue with numpy

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/spark-8669fa0e-7864-4d2d-8fb4-5d0f2d068f5a/dependencies.zip/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
  File "/tmp/spark-8669fa0e-7864-4d2d-8fb4-5d0f2d068f5a/dependencies.zip/numpy/core/multiarray.py", line 12, in <module>
  File "/tmp/spark-8669fa0e-7864-4d2d-8fb4-5d0f2d068f5a/dependencies.zip/numpy/core/overrides.py", line 7, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy.core._multiarray_umath'
```

So it correctly unzips dependencies.zip file which on the path.

If someone knows another way, I will be happy to hear it.

Mich